# Problemas con Pipe en Ionic 4

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic4

He creado un *pipe* en Ionic 4 y importandolo como se supone que se debe importar pero cuando lo intento utilizar en cualquier archivo html de mis páginas señal que no se puede encontrar dicho elemento.

**Importacion**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';

import { DatosSubnetService } from './service/datos-subnet.service';
import { IpsPipe } from './pipes/ips.pipe';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, IpsPipe],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [BrowserModule, IonicModule.forRoot(), AppRoutingModule],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    DatosSubnetService,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

**PIPE**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'ips'
})
export class IpsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  ip: string;

  transform(ip: number[], args: any[]): string {
    this.ip = String(ip.join('.'));
    return this.ip;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resuelto, en lugar de poner el pipe como recurso general en `app.module.ts` se debe de colocar en donde realmente se usa el pipe, en mi caso fue en la pantalla de `subnet.page.ts` por lo que quedaria de la siguiente forma.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule } from '@ionic/angular';

import { SubnetPage } from './subnet.page';
import { IpsPipe } from '../pipes/all-pipes.pipe';


const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SubnetPage
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ],
  declarations: [SubnetPage, IpsPipe]
})
export class SubnetPageModule {}
```